# Is it possible to install Ack on windows without network?

Tags: ack

I use two PC for work, one can access internet, the other one can not, it's for development.

I want to install Ack for better use VIM on the development PC.

Is there a Installer for Ack or other ways can install it without network?

PC are both Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-file version of ack is available at http://beyondgrep.com/install/.  You can download that one file on an Internet-connected computer, transfer it over to your non-Internet computer, and put it somewhere in your Windows path.  I wish I could be more specific on what to do.

You will have to have Perl installed on the machine, however, since ack requires Perl.

You may want to post to the ack-users mailing list and get some tips there: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ack-users